# How do I solve this TypeError: props.onSubmit is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, rxjs

I'm currently building a ToDo-List App in react and I'm getting the following error message:

TypeError: props.onSubmit is not a function:

```
  16 | const handleSubmit = e => {
  17 |   e.preventDefault();
  18 | `enter code here`
> 19 |   props.onSubmit({
     | ^  20 |     id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
  21 |     text: input
  22 |   });
```

This is the function that I wrote inside of the following file TodoForm.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function TodoForm(props) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(props.edit ? props.edit.value : '');

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  });

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    props.onSubmit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      text: input
    });
    setInput('');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='todo-form'>
      {props.edit ? (
        <>
          <input
            placeholder='Update your item'
            value={input}
            onChange={handleChange}
            name='text'
            ref={inputRef}
            className='todo-input edit'
          />
          <button onClick={handleSubmit} className='todo-button edit'>
            Update
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <input
            placeholder='Add a todo'
            value={input}
            onChange={handleChange}
            name='text'
            className='todo-input'
            ref={inputRef}
          />
          <button onClick={handleSubmit} className='todo-button'>
            Add todo
          </button>
        </>
      )}
    </form>
  );
}

export default TodoForm;
```

Could someone please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well what have you declared `props.onSubmit` to be? What did you pass into `TodoForm`?

Comment: How do you pass the `onSubmit` prop to `<TodoForm />`? That would look something like `<TodoForm obSubmit={(formValues) => doStuff(formValues)} />`

Comment: I send it to the return statement inside of the form `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}`

Comment: @AndresHaro No we need to see the higher level, where you render `TodoForm`. That is where props are declared.

Comment: This is inside of Todo.js - `if (edit.id) {
    return <TodoForm edit={edit} onSubmit={submitUpdate} />;
  }`

Comment: Inside of my TodList.js where I list all my variable to hold my variables, I say that has to return `return (
    <>
      <h1>What's the Plan for Today?</h1>
      <TodoForm onSubmit={addTodo} />
      <Todo
        todos={todos}
        completeTodo={completeTodo}
        removeTodo={removeTodo}
        updateTodo={updateTodo}
      />
    </>
  );`

Comment: You're going to have to follow it up the chain to find out where it becomes undefined. What is `addTodo`?

Comment: That's my variable to add an extra task to the todo list. [link] (https://github.com/hvaandres/TodoList_React)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BrianThompson is right that the problem is way higher up in the chain.  I looked at your repo and it's actually in `App.js`.

You have a component `TodoList` which calls `TodoForm` with the `onSubmit` function that it created.  But in your `App.js` you have accidentally used `TodoForm` instead of `TodoList`!  You cannot use `TodoForm` directly without supplying the necessary props, so you get an error.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="todo-app">
      <TodoForm />
     <h1>To-Do App</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In file https://github.com/hvaandres/TodoList_React/blob/main/todo_list_v2/src/App.js you call `TodoForm` without supplying the `onSubmit` function as a prop:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="todo-app">
      <TodoForm />
     <h1>To-Do App</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You need to create onSubmit function and pass it to to TodoForm like that:

```js
const onSubmit = () => {
  // implement what you are trying to do in this function
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="todo-app">
      <TodoForm onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
     <h1>To-Do App</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```